# Tomcat doesn't respond when SSL certificate installaed

Tags: tomcat, ssl, https, tomcat7, ssl-certificate

When I've installed an new ssl certificate, https connector stopped working - It doesn't respond to the requests sent by a client.

No firewall resides between the client and the server. Also wireshark shows that there is an exchange of packets between a client and a server when http request is sent to http port.

Everything worked fine with the old certificate that has been installed previously. The problem only with the new certificate. So, it looks like certificate could be the issue but I need to know what is the exact problem. Other reports of similar issues that I've found were resolved by certificate regeneration but since I am not the one who is generating the certificate I would prefer to request the new certificate only when I am sure that this resolves the issue.

There is no error in catalina.out log or any log message that would give a clue. 
Is there any way to enable verbose logging that would show what happens in http connector when it gets the request? Any other way to troubleshoot it?

More details on how configuration has been done below:

I used the following command to create a new keystore and import the certificate:

```
keytool -import -alias some_alias -keystore .keystore2 -file certfile
```

The certificate can be read from .keystore2 successfully by keytool

I also tried to add the new certificate to the existing keystore. It was successfully added and could be read by keytool but the strange thing is that http connector was not be able to find it by its alias(though keytool shows the correct alias).

Here is the config for the HTTP connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
                 SSLEnabled="true" maxPostSize="0"
               maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="
some_path/.keystore2"
               keystorePass="xxxxxx" />
```

HTTPS port is open:

```
netstat -antp |grep LIST    
tcp        0      0 :::8443                     :::*    LISTEN      3529/java
```

No errors in catalina.out. There are messages that show that the HTTP connector is up and running:

```
Jul 12, 2015 7:12:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8443"]
```

Versions:

```
Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
Server built:   Nov 20 2011 07:36:25
Server number:  7.0.23.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-504.el6.x86_64
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_04-b20
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try and change the HTTPS connector protocol to this: " protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol"

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help. Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution?